# dotnet run won't use bower packages

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, bower, .net-core

I have an asp.net core web application I'm trying to get running in a Docker container.

From powershell, inside the project file, I can run `> dotnet restore` then `> dotnet run` and it will run a docker container:

```
PS E:\Projects\...> dotnet run
Project MyProject (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: E:\Projects\...
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

The only issue is that when I go to `localhost:5000`, it appears like the bower packages (like Angular) aren't installed. While the webpages/controllers all work, the front end Angular won't run.

It doesn't return a 404 not found, it just doesn't bind any of the Angular stuff.

If I run the same project from Visual Studio (2015) it includes/runs Angular with no worries, and the website looks like it should. Viewing the source, you can see that the angular files have been included.

My DockerFile is:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY published .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

but I think it's an issue with the `dotnet run` command.

How can I ensure the bower packages are included and run inside the docker container?

---

**Edit 1**

I tried doing `dotnet build` then `bower install` then `dotnet run` with no luck.

After that I tried to publish it wtih `dotnet publish -o published` and then ran it with `dotnet MyProject.dll` from the published directory and it did the same thing.

When I run the project from Visual Studio the page has all the scripts included:

```
...
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular/angular.js?v=IuVz88ct2cRJMIP8PVY9rcWTcd2eXzzvz3cdkmfoX2k"></script>
...
```

But when I run it using both `dotnet run` and `dotnet publish` then `dotnet MyProject.dll` those scripts aren't included in the page source.

---

**Fixed**

Turns out that I was running `dotnet run`, which meant it was running in Production mode.

There's a file in the views  `Views\Shared\Components\_EnvironmentFooter.cshtml` which is where all the scripts are included for the page. The only issue was that the scripts were included in the Development environment, but not the Production environment.

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

I included the scripts from development in Production/Staging environment - No longer an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not adding the scripts from bower to the production code. See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Bower dependencies are typically handled by `dotnet publish` based on the `scripts` element of `project.json`.  If you don't want to run `dotnet publish`, try running `bower install` between `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run`.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your response. I gave that a go (see updated question)